# ResourceInUseException after reinit terraform

Tags: terraform

I once set up terraform and did `terraform init` and `terraform apply` (as well as `plan`) and they worked fine. Then I accidentally deleted the `terraform.tfstate` file in my s3 bucket. So I redo `terraform init`, which worked fine, but got some trouble on `terraform apply`. I got a bunch of errors of

```
aws_dynamodb_table.****: ResourceInUseException: Table already exists: ****
    status code: 400, request id: ****
```

How can I fix this?

ps. I've tried `terraform refresh`. It does not fix the problem.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`terraform import`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/usage.html) to [import your DynamoDB table](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/dynamodb_table.html#import) with something like:

```
terraform import aws_dynamodb_table.my_table my_table
```

Your config you should have something like this:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "my_table" {
  name = "my_table"
  # ...
}
```

Obviously replace the `my_table` with your table name.

Comment: Thanks for responding! yes I did. the problem still exist :(

Comment: Thanks again! this time I got error when doing `import`: `Error: resource address "aws_dynamodb_table.****" does not exist in the configuration.`

Comment: right, you need to look at what the actual name is in your config, I'm assuming it's not called `****`

Comment: I have the config `resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "my_table" { ... }`,  `terraform import aws_dynamodb_table.my_table {$ARN}` still complains about resource address not existing

Comment: try using the table name instead of the id, just saw here https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/dynamodb_table.html#import that they use that instead of the id for dynamo

Comment: Works! should use table name instead of ARN. Btw, the address is not exactly aws_dynamodb_table.my-table, I found the complete address by doing terraform plan. Thank you so much!

Comment: To avoid such accidental deletion in S3, use versioning. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html